Chokidar not giving proper events in network shared path
Chokidar is not giving proper events when multiple users are watching same network shared path.
For example :- Shared Net Patrh is = \nas\TempShare\Test
Now multiiple users from their individual machines watching same path then chokidar is not giving proper events.
**Here is the chokidar config options we are using :-** 
ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../, // ignore dotfiles
    persistent: true,
    depth: 99,
    alwaysStat: true,
    awaitWriteFinish: {
        stabilityThreshold: 3000,
        pollInterval: 100
    },
    ignorePermissionErrors: false,
    ignoreInitial: true,
    usePolling:true,
    interval:100,
    binaryInteval:300,
    atomic: 1000 // or a custom 'atomicity delay', in milliseconds (default 100)

3 Users are watching same directory over a mentioned network shared path. If anyone user made any changes in file, then change event should come in other 2 users also and that too only once, as 1st user have edited file only once. But here we are facing issues or can say that chokidar is not giving change events properly. After making single change in any file, its giving multiple events for other 2 users.
That shared folder have some other files also, even if we don't make any changes in file still change, add, unlink events are coming from chokidar for random files.
Could anyone help us here?
Any help would be really appreciated.
